# Closing a file after using np.load (using Spyder)

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, spyder, winscp

I am loading a file:

```
a= np.load('myfile.npz')
```

and then doing things with `a`

After a while I regenerate `myfile.npz` (on a remote machine).

When I attempt to copy the file across (using WinSCP) from the remote machine it fails, reporting:

```
System Error.  Code: 32.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I've tried this:

```
>>> a.fid
<open file 'myfile.npz', mode 'rb' at 0x058A78B8>
>>> a.fid.close()
>>> a.fid
<closed file 'myfile.npz', mode 'rb' at 0x058A78B8>
```

However, the file copy still fails.

If I close the python interpreter, the copy succeeds.

What is causing this porblem? Do I need to close `myfile.npz` (I had thought this was handled automatically) first? If so, how do I do it?

I'm using a python console with in the Spyder IDE on Win7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) also works:

```
del a
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using the [`with` context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012488/1426065):

```
with np.load('myfile.npz') as a:
    do_stuff(a)

do_morestuff() # a is closed now
```

Context managers automatically take care of closing the resource once you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks, that works but I'm playing around with a on the command line. The tabs required before each command are irksome  (as I'm copying previous commands as well).