# How to load and close numpy file in iterator

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, syntax-error

I'm trying to figure out how I can load thousands of numpy files using an iterator. To do this without overflowing my memory, I need to be able to open and close the files.

I have a list called `train_data` that holds a list of numpy filenames. I can load one numpy array using

```
np.load(train_data[0])
```

but if I try to load it using an iterator and the context manager (which according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064349/4237080) would help with memory, as it should close the file by itself after it is done with it), it throws an error.

```
class AbstractIterator(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for abstract_filename in train_data:
            with np.load(abstract_filename) as a:
                print(abstract_filename)

iterator =  AbstractIterator()
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-53-12ff2d39b102>", line 8, in <module>
    for i in AbstractIterator():
  File "<ipython-input-53-12ff2d39b102>", line 5, in __iter__
    with np.load(abstract_filename) as a:
AttributeError: __enter__

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1151, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1483, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1441, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 725, in getmodule
    file = getabsfile(object, _filename)
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 709, in getabsfile
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(_filename))
  File "/Users/briennakh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 376, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I load and properly close the file after I'm done working with it, in an iterator?

EDIT: I need an iterator. Not something that is a workaround. I'm using this with gensim, which takes an iterator.

I have tried to incorporate the answer into my code.

```
class DocumentIterator(object):
    def load_documents(self):
        for filename in self.filenames: 
            loaded_file = np.load(filename)
            tag = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
            abstract = TaggedDocument(words=loaded_file, tags=[tag])
            try:
                yield abstract
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error!' + str(e))
            finally:
                del loaded_file
                print('Closed ' + tag)

    def __init__(self, filenames):
        self.filenames = filenames
        self.generator = self.load_documents()

    def __iter__(self):
        self.generator = self.load_documents() # Reset the iterator
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        abstract = next(self.generator)
        return abstract
```

This works.

Comment: I’m glad you found the answer. By the way, ``os.path`` is an older usage. If your Python >= 3.4, 
I suggest you use ``pathlib.Path``, it can do almost everything ``os.path`` can do, and it is very comfortable to use!
[ref1](https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-the-python-pathlib-module/) [ref2: document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that does you must implement `iter` to help you close.

You can use `contextlib.contextmanager` to help you to do something after leaving the `with`.
In this way, you don't have to implement `iter`.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from contextlib import contextmanager


def generate_test_files(numbers_of_files=3):
    test_data = np.arange(10)
    rtn_list = []
    for i in range(numbers_of_files):
        file_name = f'test_{i}.npy'
        if not Path(file_name).exists():
            np.save(file_name, test_data)
        rtn_list.append(file_name)
    return rtn_list


@contextmanager
def block_numpy_load(file_name):
    obj = np.load(file_name)
    try:
        yield obj
    except:
        ...
    finally:
        del obj
        print('release')


train_file_list = generate_test_files()
for f in train_file_list:
    with block_numpy_load(f) as data:
        print(data)
```

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
release
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
release
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
release
```

## OOP

If you want to OO may reference the following.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import Iterator
import abc


def generate_test_files(numbers_of_files=3):
    test_data = np.arange(10)
    rtn_list = []
    for i in range(numbers_of_files):
        file_name = f'test_{i}.npy'
        if not Path(file_name).exists():
            np.save(file_name, test_data)
        rtn_list.append(Path(file_name))
    return rtn_list


@contextmanager
def block_numpy_load(file_name):
    obj = np.load(file_name)
    try:
        yield obj
    except:
        ...
    finally:
        # del obj
        print('release')


class NpLoadMixin(abc.ABC):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Path]:
        for file in self.train_data:
            yield file

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def start_iter(self):
        for file in self:
            with block_numpy_load(file) as a:
                ...


class MyAI(NpLoadMixin):
    def __init__(self, train_data):
        self.train_data = train_data

    def start_iter(self):
        for file in self:
            with block_numpy_load(file) as np_array:
                print(np_array)


train_file_list = generate_test_files()
obj = MyAI(train_file_list)
obj.start_iter()
```

Comment: I'm more confused now. I tried to put your answer into my code, but it's not working. I edited my question. I need an iterator.

Comment: I think I got it. Edited my answer. Thank you