# Why the last node is not getting deleted Linked List?

Tags: python, python-2.7, linked-list

I have below code. I am trying to delete the last node. But the node is not getting deleted. The `temp` is still holding the all the `data`. I did not understand that, in Python the assignment means `deep copy or shallow copy`?

```
class ll:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
    def adddata(self, data):
        if not self.next:
            self.next = ll(data)
            return
        self.next.adddata(data)
def display(root):
    if root == None:
        return
    print root.data
    display(root.next)

def delete_last(root):
    temp = root
    myfrontptr = root.next
    while myfrontptr.next != None:
        root = root.next
        myfrontptr = myfrontptr.next
    if root.next != None and myfrontptr.next == None:
        del myfrontptr
    return temp

l = ll(1)
l.adddata(5)
l.adddata(3)
l.adddata(2)
l.adddata(0)
l.adddata(4)
l = delete_last(l)
display(l)
```

Comment: `del` doesn't mean "delete this object". It means "unset this variable". You unset the `myfrontptr` local variable, but that doesn't do anything to the list.

Comment: It's almost never useful to `del` a variable.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it seems odd you create an old style class.  In python 2.7 you need to declare `class ll(object)` if you want (and you do -- don't you??!!) new style classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `del`, you should unreference the last node.

Replace

```
if root.next != None and myfrontptr.next == None:
    del myfrontptr
```

With

```
if root.next != None and myfrontptr.next == None:
    root.next = None
```

Comment: `del` wont be helpful? If Yes, what about `myfrontptr` it is still in the memory. So, `Python ` will take care of it by its own? or we need to delete it?

Comment: Python's garbage collector will take care of it. `del` in mainly used when you want to remove an object from a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set `next` reference in element before last element when last element is removed:

```
def delete_last(root):
    temp = root
    myfrontptr = root.next
    while myfrontptr.next != None:
        root = root.next
        myfrontptr = myfrontptr.next
    if root.next != None and myfrontptr.next == None:
        del myfrontptr # you don't need this, myfrontptr is a local name anyway
        root.next = None
    return temp
```

`del` [does not remove anything from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python). Unline in C/C++, in python [memory is freed by Garbage Collector](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm). And even in C/C++ you'd have to overwrite the last element pointer/reference.