# Use of del in Python

Tags: python

I wrote the following code in python. I was not able to understand the logic behind the output. Can you help me out?

```
a= [1,2,3]
print(a)
del a[1]
print(a)
```

The result came out to be
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen? You deleted the element at index `1`.

Comment: The following two links may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python

Comment: indexes start at 0 in python. Maybe that's what you didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Ill try to be as comprehensive as I can

```
a= [1,2,3] is a list of integers
```

so print(a) will output the entire list `[1,2,3]`

now python has a way it counts items in a list with '0' denoting the first item.'1' the second item and so on. In you're case:

```
item 0 = 1
item 1 = 2
item 2 = 3
del a(1) = del '2'
```

the new list is:

```
print (a) = [1,3]
```