# confusion in python printing the lists

Tags: python, list, printing

In the following python code, I have a list i.e. `to_do_list` of two lists i.e. `other_events` and `grocery_list` where I inserted an item in `grocery_list` and then deleted it.

My confusion is, when I updated `grocery_list`, `to_do_list` is automatically updated but when I deleted `grocery_list`, `to_do_list` is not updated... why?

```
grocery_list = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']

other_events =['pick up kids','do laundry', 'dance class']

to_do_list = [other_events, grocery_list]

print(to_do_list)

grocery_list.insert(1,'onions');

print(grocery_list)

del grocery_list

print(to_do_list)
```

its output is:

```
[['pick up kids', 'do laundry', 'dance class'], ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']]
['banana', 'onions', 'mango', 'apple']
[['pick up kids', 'do laundry', 'dance class'], ['banana', 'onions', 'mango', 'apple']]
```

Comment: use del grocery_list[:] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why, when you update `grocery_list` your object `to_do_list` is updated is that your list `to_do_list` contain a only *reference* on `grocery_list`.

Now, why after deleting `grocery_list`, `to_do_list` is not updated is that the keywork `del` doesn't delete the object on which but only delete `grocery_list` from the namespace.

Here is a quote from the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) on what `del` does :

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or
>   global namespace

Answer (score 1):

use  `del grocery_list[:]` instead 
ouput :

```
[['pick up kids', 'do laundry', 'dance class'], ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']]
['banana', 'onions', 'mango', 'apple']
[['pick up kids', 'do laundry', 'dance class'], []]
```

**but why** ?
assume we have a list :
`grocery_list = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']`

```
del grocery_list
grocery_list
```

when you use this to delete list program raise an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#619>", line 1, in <module>
    del grocery_list
NameError: name 'grocery_list' is not defined
```

in this code you used `del grocery_list` which only delete `grocery_list`  (**Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace**) and don't clear the list you must use `del grocery_list[:]` to compeletely delete it
 for more detail for `del` ref to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

grocery_list has many references to it and the

`del grocery_list`

will only remove one reference while other references will exists.

One way to remove all the references from a list is to use slice assignment

```
del grocery_list[:]
```