# Python3: Why is __del__ called after reassignment of a new object variable?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have the following code in Python:

```
class Test:
    def __del__(self):
        print("del is called")


a = Test()
a = Test()
```

yields to the following output:

```
`del is called`
```

Why is that and what is the concept behind this?

Is "del" called after every reassignment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is del useful in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python)

Comment: I would like to know, why "del" is implicitly called in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__del__` is called because there's no more references to the original `a`, causing it to be garbage-collected. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) for details.

You only get the output once, because

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.