# Removing Keys and Values from nested list in dict

Tags: python

Using Python 3, I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the key and value pairs for "BasicPay" and "TotalPay".

```
 d = {
    "PersonDetail": [
        {"EmployeeNumber": "123", "ID": 212, "BasicPay": 0.0000, "TotalPay": 0.0000},
        {"EmployeeNumber": "987", "ID": 213, "BasicPay": 0.0000, "TotalPay": 0.0000}
        ]
    }
```

I'm going round in circles at the moment, any pointers to get me going would be appreciated!

Comment: use `pop()` or `del`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147100/2864740 (wrt. `del` in context, similarly search for..)

Comment: `for lst in d.values():` `for subdict in lst:` `for key in ("BasicPay", "TotalPay"):` `del subdict[key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. A for loop to go through each element.

```
d = {
    "PersonDetail": [
        {"EmployeeNumber": "123", "ID": 212, "BasicPay": 0.0000, "TotalPay": 0.0000},
        {"EmployeeNumber": "987", "ID": 213, "BasicPay": 0.0000, "TotalPay": 0.0000}
        ]
    }

for employee in d["PersonDetail"]:
    employee.pop("BasicPay")
    employee.pop("TotalPay")

print(d)
```

Comment: `del` seems more appropriate, since you don't need to return the value.

Comment: While you're right, .pop() is more commonly known, so I went with that.