# How to write the value of z into the string?

Tags: python, variables

```
import random

x = 1

z = random.randint(0,255)

if x != z:
    print('unsuccessful')
    
if x = z:
    
    print('successful')

    f = open("C:\Users\AsusTUF\ai.txt", "a")
    del = text.replace('z = random.randint(0,255)','z = '
```

So i want to write value of z into the file, but I dont have an idea on how to do it! Thanks in advance for the help.

Keep in mind I am new to python so I tried return z but did not even run that because i know it wont work.

Comment: `f.write(str(z))` writes z to the file.

Comment: Im confusioned. Whats the input file look as like, currently? and then what is the desired or result output?

Comment: note here, the `if x != z:`, then in latter case don't need a `if x = z:` - this is a good case for an `else:` actually.

Comment: Since `x` equals 1, and `z` equals `x`, you could just directly write "1" into the file. Although that is probably not the essence of your question.

Comment: Don't use [`del`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python) as variable name.

Comment: Replace the last line with `f.write(f'z = random.randint(0,255), z = {z}\n')`. And don't forget to close the file afterwards.

Comment: But is that the line in your file? `z = random.randint(0,255)` ? That doesnt make sense, why it would be in a file (the string value i mean).

Comment: Probably you want to use `if x == z:` (with two equals).

Comment: Try `f.write(str(z))` instead of the the line `del = tex....` to write z to the file. Btw, there is only 1/256 probability for x to be equal to z. Also check if you meant to use `'x == z'` in the if statement.

Comment: `text` is not defined anywhere in your code. Are you trying to write `z` in a string or in a text file? There're many ways you can [format strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings). Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) is always a good place to start.

Comment: TBH, that the line: `del = ...` : it *won't work* anyway. Not run the code, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `f.write('text')`. For example:

```
import random

x = 1

z = random.randint(0,255)

if x != z:
    print('unsuccessful')
    
if x == z:
    
    print('successful')

    f = open("C:\Users\AsusTUF\ai.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(z))
    f.close()
```

Also it's not a good idea to use `del` as a variable name once it is a keyword from the language.

Answer (score 0):

The line being as such:

```
del = ...
```

It 'll not actually work.

Here is the repro example using a Python REPL:

```
py
zsh: command not found: py
python
Python 3.8.14 (default, Nov  7 2022, 11:52:33) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> del = ...
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    del = ...
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even other operator, being as such `in`:

```
>>> in = ...
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    in = ...
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Rename it, then We All Good ™️:

```
>>> IN = ...
>>> IN
Ellipsis
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers, I assume that you are trying to check how many runs it takes to get the random value equals to `x`.

It can easily be done by adding a while loop with a counter.

```py
import random

x = 1
count = 0  # Counter
while True:  # Loop indefinitely
    z = random.randint(0, 255)  # Generate random number
    count += 1  # Increasing the counter

    if x != z:
        print('Unsuccessful: %d' % count)
    else:
        print('Successful: %d' % count)
        f = open("i.txt", "a")  # You can also give relative path here
        f.write(str(z))  # Writing the value to file
        break  # Breaking the loop
```